# 1001_s = 19684_10 solving for S in and stating the base

Tags: equation, radix

This is a homework question and I don't want the solution, I just want a reference to how to solve similar questions like this. I believe it's explained my course textbook, *"Computer Organization & Architecture: Themes and Variations"*, but I currently cannot afford the textbook.

Here's the question:

> For each of the following numbers, state the base in use; that is,
>   what are the values of `r`, `s`, and `t`?
>
> 1. `25_r = 23_10`
> 2. `1001_s = 19684_10`
> 3. `1011_t = 4931_10`

I recognize it's similar to solving an equation. I'm guessing I have to find `r`, `s` and `t` and they will be a specific base that matches the base ten number.
I tried searching online for similar questions but I'm not sure what to search for so I have no clue where to start for solving these equations.

Comment: What precisely is your problem? Do you understand what it means for different numbers to be in different bases? How to calculate the decimal version of a number given its base?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. This is a math question. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jonrsharpe, my problem is solving for the variables r, s, and t. I do not know how to go about doing this. I do understand number systems and but I don't know a specific method for solving these questions.

Comment: @user134454 solving for `r`, `s` and `t` is your **task**; if you understand number systems, what's your *problem*? As Raymond points out, this isn't a programming problem.

Comment: @user134454 let me ask you this: how do you convert from a base `b` number to a base 10 number?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok i'm sorry I wasn't being explicit. Lemme just explain my entire thought set on this question. 
I know that for example, AB_16 = 171_10. I'm assuming this question is asking me to find the base variable which would make the equation equal. So for say the first question 25_r = 23_10, r = 9. Plugging this in would result in 25_9 = 23_10 which is true. However I did this only through guess and check. I want to know if there is a method that would allow me to solve for the variable without guessing and checking.

Comment: @josh, well I usually use the division method in which I just keep dividing the decimal number by the new base to get the quotient and remainder and until the quotient is 0. However the new base is given and in this case the new base is a variable which is not given. I want to know how to solve for this variable without guessing and checking.

Comment: It's not just *"similar to solving an equation"* - you're solving the equation `(2 * (r ** 1)) + (5 * (r ** 0)) = 23`. But, one last time, *this isn't a programming problem*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you! That equation was exactly what I needed. Anyways, I apologize for posting in the wrong exchange.

Comment: @user134454 see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure to convert from base *b* to base 10 is to multiply each digit in position *k* (from right to left, starting at 0) by *b^k*.

I won't give away all of the answers but for 25 in base *s*, it is `2 * s^1 + 5 * s^0 = 23` which reduces to `2 * s + 1 = 23` or `2 * s = 18`. Then *s* = 9.

Since this is a programming website, I'll throw in a pseudocoded procedure to do check your answers with:

```
procedure base_b_to_ten(int[] n, int base) {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int k=0; k<n.length; k++) {
        sum = sum + pow(n[n.length - k], base);
    }

    return base;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I definitely should have posted to math.stackexchange but I really appreciate you helping me out anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search should work for semi efficient starting at the quarter(Or anywhere really) of the base 10 point.

Converting to base 10 is fairly simple, so just guess and check each time doing regular binary search, if the number is too big then the base is too big.  If the number is too small then the base is too small.

Answer (score 0):

I just think this would be good for math.stackexchange.com because of the possibility to code latex answers.
Anyway, I think this is an interesting question.
A number n in base b, having digits a_0,...,a_k with a_0 being the rightmost digit, is
n=sum from i=0 to k: a_i*b^i
Here, a_i means a with subscript index i.
So, to solve this, I insert your first example for a_i:

```
1*b^3 + 1*b^0 = 19684  
=>b^3 + b = 19684  
=>b*(b^2 + 1) = 19684
```

Now this is a third-degree polynomial.
I, personally can't solve thus analytically, though I know there are cardano formulas for that. For longer numbers you will have even higher degree polynomials, which can be solved by a human with a good guess, or, with a computer.
Good luck!

Comment: It just came to my mind, that in b*(b^2 + 1)=19684 is the knowledge that, if there is an integer solution b, it is already part of the factorisation of 19684.
Factoring 19684 is trying prime integer divisors until a prime is left: 19684=2*9842=2*2*4921=2*2*7*703=...  
Once there is a complete factorisation, I would try to 'put' the factors either on the b or the (b^2 + 1) side and see if some solution for b arises.

Comment: Argh, i made a mistake in my post. `b^0` is clearly 1, not `b`. So: `b^3 + 1 = 19684` `=>` `b^3 = 19683` `=>` `b^3 = 3*6561 = 3*3*2187 = 3*3*3*729 = 3*3*3*3*243 = 3*3*3*3*3*81` `=>` `b=3^3=27`